# Cocoa / Core Animation: everything jumps around upon becomeFirstResponder()

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, nstextfield

The gist: I have a bunch of views nested in one `MainView`. When I call `becomeFirstResponder()` on an `NSTextField` that's nested in one of those views, suddenly every view within `MainView` jumps to a semi-arbitrary older position.

The actual cause could be any one of a number of things, leading among which likely is that I've only been writing Cocoa for about a week.

Here's the actual structure:

```
MainView: NSView
 ├ ContactTile: NSView (layer-backed)
 |  └ /* several CALayers */
 ├ ContactTile
 ├ …
 ├ ContactTile
 └ StatusTile: NSView (layer-backed)
    ├ SearchIcon: NSView (layer-backed)
    |  └ SearchIconLayer: CALayer
    └ NSTextField
```

I've backed all my core business logic with ReactiveCocoa, with async dispatches back to the main UI thread for doing drawing-related operations.

The `StatusTile` is initialized and added as a subview immediately when `MainView` is created, and its position is set to the top-right area of the screen. The `ContactTiles` are created and added dynamically — creation and subview adding happens in one ReactiveCocoa observer (leaving the initial position to just be `(0, 0)`), and in another "relayout" observer all the `ContactTile`s as well as the `StatusTile` are animated and positioned with code that looks roughly like:

```swift
let anim = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "position");
let (from, to) = /* bunch of positional calculation */;
anim.fromValue = NSValue.init(point: from);
anim.toValue = NSValue.init(point: to);

tile.layer!.removeAnimation("contacttile-layout");
tile.layer!.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "contacttile-layout");
tile.layer!.position = to;
```

This all works perfectly as long as I don't do anything to do with `becomeFirstResponder`; the tiles animate from and to their expected positions, and stay there as expected. If I check in on their `.position` at rest, they're exactly where I'd expect.

But now I add code that in a separate ReactiveCocoa observer listens for a global hotkey. That global hotkey signal triggers a relayout at the same time, causing the animation/layout code you see above to go. But it also triggers a separate observer that calls `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` in the `StatusTile` view above.

```swift
GlobalInteraction.sharedInstance.activated.observeNext { activated in
    if activated {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { self._searchField.becomeFirstResponder(); });
    } else {
        self._searchField.stringValue = "";
    }
}
```

Now what happens is that the animation proceeds exactly as expected, but upon animation completion, each element resets to its initial position as described a few paragraphs ago: the `StatusTile` reverts to its initial top-right position, and every `ContactTile` reverts to `(0, 0)`.

If I check on their actual `.position`s at rest, they do indeed report `(0, 0)`. But if I check their `.position` immediately after the calculation block above, everything is where I'd expect it to be. Even weirder, the `.becomeFirstResponder()` call pretty consistently happens *before* I perform the relayout animation setup above. So somehow the call messes with my positions *after* all is said and done as far as my code is concerned.

When something subsequently happens that changes the layout, like typing in the text field or other external inputs, everything goes back to working exactly as expected, even while the text field has focus. It's only on that initial activation that everything bounces around.

Some possibly related quirks:

- I'm rendering onto a transparent, borderless window, so everything is just floating in space.
- The application in general receives focus as part of that same global hotkey.
- ?? not sure what else, but it's kind of a strange application and I'm new to Cocoa, so please ask if you have clarifying questions.

Comment: Apple says about `becomeFirstResponder`: "Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder: method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly. "

Comment: Oh jeez. That's what I get for learning things off Stack Overflow — thanks for the tip! Sadly though, even with `self.window!.makeFirstResponder(self._searchField);` it's still exhibiting the same problem. Got any other ideas?

Comment: Tried one more thing: eliminated the animations altogether, so I'm just directly setting each `nsview.layer!.position` — it exhibits the same problem. So it may be CALayer related, but it's not actually animation-related.